# python read write questions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, read-write

I'm trying to grep some information from my .json file, and save it into a .txt file. Everything went well until I open my .txt file and found that the output of the file is not the same as I wish for. Here are my codings.

```
import numpy as np
import json
from numpy import *

with open('myjson.json','rb') as f:
   data = json.load(f)
   alllist=[]
   qq=[0,1,2]
   for classes in range(len(data["shapes"])):   
       x1 = data["shapes"][classes]["points"][0][0]
       y1 = data["shapes"][classes]["points"][0][1]
       x2 = data["shapes"][classes]["points"][1][0]
       y2 = data["shapes"][classes]["points"][1][1]
       c = data["shapes"][classes]["label"]
       if c=='T':
           c=qq[2]
       elif c=="FAN":
           c=qq[1]
       elif c=="DIMM":
           c=qq[0]
               
       alist = [int(x1),int(y1),int(x2),int(y2),int(c)]
       alllist.append(alist)
       
   final = np.reshape(alllist,(13,5))    
   print(final, file = open('mytest.txt','a'))
```

The output is

```
[[446 438 673 738   2]
 [813  97 694 239   1]
 [689  97 586 232   1]
 [584  93 474 233   1]
 [469  90 355 232   1]
 [783 345 758 748   0]
 [754 343 731 746   0]
 [728 346 710 744   0]
 [704 346 676 747   0]
 [441 343 414 742   0]
 [411 343 385 743   0]
 [384 341 361 739   0]
 [360 341 334 743   0]]
```

And when I go for `print(final[0])` the output is

```
[446 438 673 738   2]
```

However, when I read the file and print the same code, it gives me output as

```
mytest = open ('mytest.txt','rb')
result = mytest.read()
print(result[0])
```

```
91
```

How can I do to make the output of 'mytest.txt' same as the output of `print(final[0])` at the beginning?

Comment: `mytest.txt` contains exactly the output you tried to print to it. You're just reading it wrong.

Comment: (`print`ing a NumPy array is generally a terrible option for data storage - it throws most of the data away for large arrays, and it's inconvenient to read even when it doesn't lose data.)

Comment: when you use standard `read()` then it always treats is as normal string or bytes ("raw data") and you have to write own code to convert it to list of numbers. You should rateher use numpy's function to save and read files and it will save in own format but when it will read it then it will convert to numpy array again.

Comment: see [numpy.savetxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) and [numpy.loadtxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html)

Comment: BTW: to access data `myjson.json` you have to use `json.load()` to convert `string` from file to `list/dict` with data - and the same is with `mytest.txt` - it needs some function to convert `string` from file to `list/dict` with data.